# Not managing to transfer my code onto a different bot

Tags: discord.js

So I have my bot which I now transferred onto a Heroku server, with this I made a new bot which I named ex Test Bot, but for some reason when I went into my config.json with the code

```
{
    "token": "DISCORD BOT ID THING"
}
```

Now when I change the following to my test bots ID which I will run from my PC, it gives me this wierd error
[image]

I really have no clue searched online couldnt fined anthing, I hope one of you guys could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using an intent that you don't have permission to use or isn't enabled.

You'll have to go to [`Discord Developer Portal`](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), choose your application, go to the `Bot` section, and enable all the intents. (Or the ones you are using.)

[image: 2]

Note that once your bot reaches 100 or more servers, this will require verification and whitelisting.

[Bot Verification and Data Whitelisting](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412)